# Python - Activity Selection - Greedy Algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x

I've done this activity selection piece of code, which is a greedy approach. I need some feedback/suggestions.

---

```
# Python 3
import random
import operator
begin = [random.randint(1, 10) for i in range(10)]
end = [x + random.randint(1, 4) for x in begin]
pair = sorted(list(zip(begin, end)), key=operator.itemgetter(1))
ls = list()
ls.append(pair[0])
for i in pair[1:]:
    if i[0] >= ls[-1][1]:
        ls.append(i)
print(ls, '>>>', len(ls), 'out of', len(pair), 'activities.')
```

Answer (score 1):

## Code readability and style -

---

I believe that good code should have good style and should be more readable and concise.

---

Let's introduce you to [*`f`*-strings](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/) -

> *To create an f-string, prefix the string with the letter* “ *`f`* ”.
>   *The string itself can be formatted in much the same way that you would
>   with
>   [**`str.format()`**](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-format-function/).*
>   *`f`*-*strings* *provide a concise and convenient way to embed python
>   expressions inside string literals for formatting.*

Which means, instead of using the outdated way of formatting strings -

> ```
> print(ls, '>>>', len(ls), 'out of', len(pair), 'activities.')
> ```

You could make it more concise -

```
print(f'{ls} >>> {len(ls)} out of {len(pair)} activities.')
```

**NOTE** - Requires [Python 3.6 and above](https://www.python.org/downloads/).

If you don't have Python 3.6 and above, you could use [*`str.format()`*](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-format-function/) -

> ***`str.format()`*** is one of the string formatting methods in Python 3, which
>   allows multiple substitutions and value formatting. This method lets
>   us concatenate elements within a string through positional formatting.

So you could write it like this -

```
print('{} >>> {} out of {} activities.'.format(ls, len(ls), len(pair)))
```

---

I would also put your code into a [function](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_functions.htm) -

> *A function is a block of organized, reusable code that is used to
>   perform a single, related action. Functions provide better modularity
>   for your application and a high degree of code reusing.*
>
> *As you already know, Python gives you many built-in functions like
>   `print()`, etc. but you can also create your own functions. These
>   functions are called user-defined functions.*

With this as the function name -

```
def activity_selection():
```

---

You should also consider using an [`if __name__ == '__main__':`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/what-does-the-if-__name__-__main__-do/) guard, like this -

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    activity_selection()
```

---

Your variables should be more descriptive -

> ```
> ls = list()
> ```

could be -

```
activity_list = list()
```

---

So, overall, your code would then look like this (in terms of code readability and style) -

```
import random
import operator

def activity_selection():
    begin = [random.randint(1, 10) for i in range(10)]
    end = [x + random.randint(1, 4) for x in begin]
    pair = sorted(list(zip(begin, end)), key=operator.itemgetter(1))
    activity_list = list()
    activity_list.append(pair[0])
    for i in pair[1:]:
        if i[0] >= activity_list[-1][1]:
            activity_list.append(i)
    print(f'{activity_list} >>> {len(activity_list)} out of {len(pair)} activities.')
    # or
    # print('{} >>> {} out of {} activities.'.format(activity_list, len(activity_list), len(pair)))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    activity_selection()
```

---

To remain concise and immaculate in writing Python programs, I suggest you have a look at [*PEP 8*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), which is Python's official style guide.

Hope this helps!

Comment: sometimes I have a Déjà vu reading some of your answers :p

Comment: @dfhwze - They all need to use f-strings. No one uses them. So I just copy-paste stuff from my other answers (for ease of writing answers) :) That's fine right?